# How do I refresh browser from server-side with node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, server, webpack-dev-middleware

I want to reload page when my html files are changed (while development) because of HMR bug in html-webpack-plugin and webpack-dev-middleware (webpack-hot-middleware) interop.

Here are two repositories where I got this problem, there are issues in both.

- [expack](https://github.com/bengrunfeld/expack)
- [webpack-template](https://github.com/ZerdoX-x/webpack-template)

---

**How can I reload page using this tools?**

- Node.js
- Express
- webpack-dev-middleware

Comment: I don't really need to solve problem, I'm going to do it by manual refreshing, but I don't know yet how to do refresh browser from server..

Comment: Maybe i can create some event and pass it to client js, where i will refresh page?

Comment: I guess you are looking for nodemon . Try installing nodemon using NPM. Correct me if I misunderstood you.

Comment: Nope, I need to refresh browser, not restart server

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a few ways to refresh a client's browser from the server.

**Server-Sent Events:**

One simple method that works across browsers and servers uses **server-sent events**. The minimal process is:

1. client sends a subscription request to server with [EventSource()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource):

```js
var evtSource = new EventSource("<server_URL>/subscribe");
```

2. client sets up a listener for incoming messages:

```js
evtSource.onmessage = function () { myPageRefresh() };
```

On the server side, set up a handler for `GET /subscribe` requests and keep track of the subscribed client:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

var client = null;

app.get('/subscribe', (req, res) => {
  // send headers to keep connection alive
  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
  };
  res.writeHead(200, headers);

  // send client a simple response
  res.write('you are subscribed');

  // store `res` of client to let us send events at will
  client = res;

  // listen for client 'close' requests
  req.on('close', () => { client = null })
});

// send refresh event (must start with 'data: ')
function sendRefresh() {
  client.write('data: refresh');
}
```

Now the server can send a refresh event at any time by simply calling `sendRefresh()`.

**lite-server:**

If you are running the server locally on your development computer, refreshing the browser is trivially easy. [lite-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lite-server) is a module that will refresh the browser whenever it detects a change to source files. It's very handy.

Comment: I will try this today. Thank you very much, I guess this what I need. And yes, I need for my local server, for development.

Comment: Did this method work for you? If it did, can you accept my answer?

Comment: Sorry.. I forgot. Ready. Thank you very much

Comment: Just make sure you use double `\n` at the end of each message, as it requires a blank line to detect that the message has been fully sent :

`res.write('you are subscribed\n\n');` & 
`res.write('data: refresh\n\n');`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events#sending_events_from_the_server